# How to set a QSpinBox when QLabel get a QImage in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QSpinBox` in my `QWidget` which I want to set only when a `QLabel` get an `QImage`. Are there any function or tool by which I can set a `QSpinBox` at any condition?

Here, how I have worked is given below

At first, I declare a `QSpinBox` object and set it's maximum

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);        
}
```

I have a `QPushButton` by pressing which, user can load an image, which will be displayed in `QLabel`.

```
void MainWindow::on_Browse_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString imagefileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "Given_Path", tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));

    if(!imagefileName.isEmpty())
    {
        image= QImage(imagefileName);
        ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));  

        spinbox= new QSpinBox(this); 
        QPoint p(100,300);
        spinbox->move(p);     
    }   
}
```

But it is not displaying any `QSpinBox` how I tried to get.

I would appreciate your any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `QSpinBox::setEnabled(bool)` function, where `QSpinBox::setEnabled(true)` will enable your `SpinBox` and similarly `QSpinBox::setEnabled(false)` will disable this.

I think you can better declare `QSpinBox` inside `MainWindow` function and put it disabled. So you can try this.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    spinbox= new QSpinBox(this);
    QPoint p(100,300);
    spinbox->move(p);   

    spinbox->setEnabled(false);    //here disabled QSpinBox
}
```

And inside Browse clicked function, you can put in enabled.

```
void MainWindow::on_Browse_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString imagefileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "Given_Path", tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));

    if(!imagefileName.isEmpty())
    {
        image= QImage(imagefileName);
        ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));       

        spinbox->setEnabled(true);  // Here enabled QSpinBox
    }    
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: If it really helps you, don't forget please to mark this answer correct and useful.